# window.history.back() not working in "Opera browser for Android"

Tags: javascript, android, opera, browser-history

Below is function for window.history.back() and i try with all major browser(using android) but when come to Opera, this function not working. This only happen in mobile.

```
function goBack()
  {
    window.history.back()
    //window.history.back(-1);
  }

 <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
 <!--<button onclick="javascript:history.back();">Go Back</button>-->
```

[Opera Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="javascript:history.back();">Go Back</button>
```